# Buttons in jquery-ui dialog box not showing when autoOpen false

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I having trouble displaying buttons in my jquery-ui dialog box after I set autoOpen to false.

I set up my dialog box with a button like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

After clicking on something else on the page, I run this line to open up my dialog box.

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
```

However, the dialog box does not show any buttons. I find that if I set `autoOpen: true`, then  the buttons will show up when the dialog box immediately opens. How can I get the buttons to show while requiring the dialog box to be opened through call (i.e. setting `autoOpen: false`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API the original code should work too:
An example from the API:

```
....
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
...
```

I didn't see the code initialized at document ready ... if the code is not initialized at document ready the part containing tags for the widget could not be loaded yet and the widget will be not initialized. When calling `$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );` an new initalization will be applied so the buttons will not appear.

Put your JS init code inside a document.ready section

```
$(function() {

  $("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Good answer, although I think you should use `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`. This executes after the DOM is loaded. `$(function(){ ... });` executes when DOM is rendered.

Comment: That's right :) but if code is short they executes almost at the same time ... but you are right.

Comment: Images can really make a big difference between rendering and loading... Often an overlooked issue.

Comment: I wrapped my call to set up the dialog box in `$(document).ready(function(){...});` but I am still have the same issue. The OK button appears only if I set `autoOpen: true` and when it is `false` everything else appears except for the button at the bottom.

Comment: Hm, so I tested the code in a separate JS file and it worked, there must be something else in my code that is messing things up.